# Wi-Fi range extension for Raspberry Pi Zero 2w

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w-2

I am building a hobby glider that uses a Raspberry pi zero 2w as the companion computer. It is connected to a pixracer flight controller.

I want to fly the glider outdoors and need to set up Wi-Fi telemetry for safety purposes and to transmit/receive data.

I can’t find anything on the internet about the range of the existing Wi-Fi module inside the raspi but I am guessing it’s not long enough for outdoor flying (the required telemetry range is up to 150m).

So far I have thought about adding an external flexible antenna (see https://youtu.be/Y648CjIiEv8) but it looks very complicated as I don’t have experience with micro soldering.

I have also thought about adding an ESP telemetry module like the ESP8266 on my raspi.

Are there any other/better ways by which I can extend the Wi-Fi range of my raspi zero 2w? I want to avoid using big antennae or dongles to keep the weight of the hardware minimum.

Comment: *"I am guessing it’s not long enough for outdoor flying"* -> I'll provide some not definitive  but probably significant support for that guess: Have you ever had a normal (as in, not intended for flying around) wifi device that was reliable enough for this @300 ft?  I realize this is highly dependent on the uplink hardware (which complicates your question), but it still seems too much of a stretch.